What type of charts does Jeppesen FD Pro X use?
In Jeppesen FD Pro X application in EFB (iPad), What type of charts are being used in Approach plates and High IFR enroute charts ?
Provide the source, if possible.

The approach charts are the standard Jeppesen charts, while the enroute map isn't analogous to any paper chart, but rather depicts selected chart components such as navaids, airways, terrain, weather, etc.
Source: I've flown with Jepp FD Pro at work for about a decade, so personal experience.
